# HTML5 Multiple File Upload. Return lastinsertid through jQuery AJAX and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, multiple-file-upload

I have an html multiple file upload:

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple">
```

I'm successfully uploading files, and writing to my db table:

**jQuery**

```
function uploadFile() {

  //some other stuff done here...

  var ajaxRequest =
    $.ajax({
      url: '../inc/ajax-upload.php',
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      processData: false, // important
      contentType: false, // important
      data: formData,
    });
    ajaxRequest.done(function(data) { 

      console.log(data); 
      lastid = 'this comes from data';
      $.each(files, function(i, file) {
        $('div#files').append('<div class="file-name" id="'+ file['name'] +'">'+file['name']+'<button class="file-delete" id="' + lastid +'">delete</button>');
      });

    })
    ajaxRequest.fail(function(jqXHR) { console.log(jqXHR); }) 
}
```

**php**

```
//CRUD stuff in another file
function pdoInsert($sql, $args) {
    $pdo = dbConnect();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($args);
    echo $pdo->lastInsertId();
}
function addFile($filename){
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_files (filename) VALUES (?)';
    $args = array($filename);
    echo pdoInsert($sql, $args);
}


//ajax.php file
$lastid = array();
foreach($_FILES as $file) {

    //do filesystem stuff

    //insert to db, get last insert id
    $lastid[] = addFile($filename);  
}
echo json_encode($lastid);
```

I want the `$lastid` from my PHP to be in JSON format like, however, it's returning a concatenated string of the insert id's, e.g. `123124[null,null]` or something like that. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must RETURN information from a function if you want to pass that value(s) back to the caller.

So change both these functions to return a value and not echo it.

```
//CRUD stuff in another file
function pdoInsert($sql, $args) {
    $pdo = dbConnect();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($args);
    //echo $pdo->lastInsertId();
    return $pdo->lastInsertId();
}
function addFile($filename){
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_files (filename) VALUES (?)';
    $args = array($filename);
    //echo pdoInsert($sql, $args);
    return pdoInsert($sql, $args);
}
```

Comment: Voilà. Thank you eagle-eyed person